# Can not write Spark dataframe into Cassandra table

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cloudera, spark-cassandra-connector

I am connecting spark on HDP3.0 with Cassandra to write a data frame into Cassandra table but receiving below error:

[image]

[image]

My code written into Cassandra table is below:

[image]

Comment: what version of Spark & Spark Cassandra Connector do you use?

Comment: Also, please insert stacktraces & source code as text, not as images - otherwise they won't be searchable

Comment: Spark 3.2.1 scala 2.11 and cassandra 3.0.9

Comment: I used spark-cassandra-connector:3.2.1-s_2.11

Answer (score 0):

HDP 3.0 is based on the Hadoop 3.1.1 that uses `commons-configuration2` library instead of `commons-configuration` that is used by Spark Cassandra Connector. You can start your `spark-shell` or `spark-submit` with following:

```
spark-shell --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.3.1,commons-configuration:commons-configuration:1.10
```

to explicitly add `commons-configuration`.